# Laravel / Sanctum / CSRF-Token Mismatch in prod

Tags: nginx, laravel-sanctum

please advise.

Really no clue what to do here.

React UI + (Laravel API + Sanctum + Nginx)

In prod and dev env headers upon authentication look very different.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working finally,

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=https://example.com

SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=.example.com
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

It works only if your api is under same domain and has a subdomain.